# Forbidden minor characterization of polytope skeletons

Tags: graph-theory, convex-polytopes, graph-minors

Say that a graph is "$d$-dimensional" if it is the node-disjoint union of $1$-skeletons of closed convex polytopes in $d$ dimensions, or a subgraph thereof.  So the $2$-dimensional graphs are exactly those that are the disjoint union of cycles and paths, the $3$-dimensional graphs are exactly the planar graphs, and so on.  (Is there a standard name for this?)

Clearly for any fixed $d$ the $d$-dimensional graphs are minor-closed, so by the graph minor theorem they can be characterized by finitely many forbidden minors.  Is it known what the forbidden minor sets are for general $d$, or even for any $d > 3$?  Alternately, is it known that the forbidden minor sets need to be unreasonably large (like how the torus needs $>1000$ forbidden minors)?

Comment: Shall the $3$-dimensional graphs be $3$-connected?

Comment: @Bullet51: No, since we are allowed to take subgraphs.

Comment: I'm wondering whether there's any obstruction at all: one can take the skeleton of the 3d cubic lattice and embed _any_ graph in it.

Comment: Why is it clear that "for any fixed $d$ the $d$-dimensional graphs are minor-closed"?